# Sum rows In R for specific values

Tags: r, statistics, sum

If i have that matrix or table:

```
    Version         Formalite      Locuteurs Realisation 
372    VF            I                Ned      1   
373    VF            I                Ned      1   
433    VF            I                Ned      0   
434    VQ            I                Ned      1
```

I want to sum the number of rows where `Realisation` is equal to 1 and version is VF and put the result in `DAF[1]`.

I tried this, but it doesn't work. I only have the value NaN in `DAF[1]`:

```
DAF[i] = sum(tmp$Version=="VF"&tmp$Realisation == 1)
```

Comment: What is `DAF[i]` in the example?

Comment: Count the number of rows?

Comment: oups,  I meant 1 instead of i, but in my code I wrote 1 so it isn't the problem

Comment: Do you have NA values in one of the columns?  In that case, use `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: But if it is NA, will it pass the conditions inside the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get the rows in which your conditions are true:

```
which( (tmp$Version=="VF") & (tmp$Realisation == 1) )
```

This will give you the rows numbers.

Now, if you want to count the number of rows, you need the length of this output, so:

```
DAF[i] <- length( which( (tmp$Version=="VF") & (tmp$Realisation == 1) ))
```

Comment: Actually there's nothing wrong, because the way he did, the output will be a vector of `T` and `F`, so when he `sum`, he will get the length. I thougth he was confusing length with sum... My bad

Comment: He will get the `sum` of TRUE values i.es. `sum(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))` and `length(which(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nrow(tmp[tmp$Version=="VF" & tmp$Realisation == 1,])
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data to data table using data.table. Install package before. 
I have DT - data table

1. Apply the command below :

DT[ (V4 ==1 & V2 =="VF" ) , .(N=.N) ]

2. You can also use dplyr package to do this . Install dplyr package before executing the below command.

I have DT - data frame

DT %>% filter(V4 ==1 & V2 =="VF" ) %>% tally()
or
DT %>% filter(V4 ==1 & V2 =="VF" ) %>% count()

3. You can also do it using base R

nrow(subset(DT , V4 == 1 & V2 == "VF))